# Prove that $\frac{n-1}{n}>\frac{2a_0a_2}{a_1^2}$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Given that the following equation $$p(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}x+a_n=0$$ has $n$ distinct real roots. Prove that
$$\frac{n-1}{n}>\frac{2a_0a_2}{a_1^2}$$

Comment: You need to add that $n$ distinct real roots. (For $n=2$, this gives the condition $a_1^2 > 4a_0 a_2$)

Comment: Yes, real roots, sorry

Comment: Woah, neat. I would have thought you could find $a_i$ that break this condition, but they all give polynomials with nondistinct or nonreal roots!

Answer (score 2):

Hint proceed by induction on $n$ beginning with the case $n = 2$, which basically reduces to the condition for when a quadratic polynomial has two distinct real roots.

Then if $f(x) = a_nx^n + \dots + a_0$ has n distinct real roots, the derivative
\begin{equation}
f'(x) = na_ox^{n-1} + (n-1)a_1x^{n-2} + (n-2)a_2x^{n-3} + \dots a_1
\end{equation}
will have $n-1$  distinct real roots by Rolle's theorem. Think about this: in each interval of consecutive roots of $f(x)$ there will be a point where the tangent line is horizontal, and there are $n-1$ intervals if you arrange the roots of $f(x)$ in increasing order. Apply induction hypothesis to $f'(x)$, and magically everything will pop out after some elementary algebra.

Let me know if this is too cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_i, 1\le i\le n$ are the $n$ distinct real roots of the given equation.

Now, if $i\ne j,(x_i-x_j)^2>0\implies x_i^2+x_j^2>2x_ix_j$

There are $^nC_2$ such pairs of $(i,j)$, each $x_i$ occurs $n-1$ times in the LHS,

so $(n-1)(\sum x_i^2)>2\sum x_ix_j$

$(n-1)\{(\sum x_i)^2-2\sum x_ix_j\}>2\sum x_ix_j$

$\implies (n-1)(\sum x_i)^2>2n\sum x_ix_j$

Now, $\sum x_i=-\frac{a_1}{a_0}$ and $\sum x_ix_j=\frac{a_2}{a_0}$ using [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html) or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).